# I am trying to tokenize the text / json file. Dont know why , but only the first tweet is getting tokenized. the code is below

Tags: python, twitter, tokenize

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
import json
import re

emoticons_str = r"""
    (?:
        [:=;] # Eyes
        [oO\-]? # Nose (optional)
        [D\)\]\(\]/\\OpP] # Mouth
    )"""

regex_str = [
    emoticons_str,
    r'<[^>]+>', # HTML tags
    r'(?:@[\w_]+)', # @-mentions
    r"(?:\#+[\w_]+[\w\'_\-]*[\w_]+)", # hash-tags
    r'http[s]?://(?:[a-z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-f][0-  9a-f]))+', # URLs
    r'(?:(?:\d+,?)+(?:\.?\d+)?)', # numbers
    r"(?:[a-z][a-z'\-_]+[a-z])", # words with - and '
    r'(?:[\w_]+)', # other words
    r'(?:\S)' # anything else
    ]

tokens_re = re.compile(r'('+'|'.join(regex_str)+')', re.VERBOSE | re.IGNORECASE)
emoticon_re = re.compile(r'^'+emoticons_str+'$', re.VERBOSE | re.IGNORECASE)


def tokenize(s):
    return tokens_re.findall(s)


def preprocess(s, lowercase=False):
    tokens = tokenize(s)
    if lowercase:
        tokens = [token if emoticon_re.search(token) else token.lower() for token in tokens]
    return tokens


#tweet = "RT @marcobonzanini: just an example! :D http://example.com #NLP"
#print(preprocess(tweet))
# ['RT', '@marcobonzanini', ':', 'just', 'an', 'example', '!', ':D', 'http://example.com', '#NLP']

with open('../script/iphone.txt', 'r') as f: 
   for line in f:
        tweet = json.loads(line)
        tokens = preprocess(tweet['text'])
        #do_something_else(tokens)
        print(json.dumps(tokens, indent=4)
```

[image: this is how it looks]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, It happen because your json file have a empty line saprate the Json. try adding:

> newline='\r\n'

so your code that reading the json file look like this:

```
with open('data/stream_sample.json', 'r', newline='\r\n') as f:
for line in f:
    tweet = json.loads(line)
    tokens = preprocess(tweet['text'])
    print(tokens)
```

Hope I helped

Comment: Tested on windows, I think that in Linux you need only the \n

Answer (score 0):

From the traceback you can see that the second line in `../script/iphone.txt` isn't valid JSON. That's why your code fails.

Comment: also i tried the same code on json file too and same error occured